# Different XML in mobile

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile, android-virtual-device

I have this XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="enter your name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="name"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="copy"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In AVD, it looks like this:

[image]

And in mobile, it looks like this:

[image]

How can I make them look the same?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: i have a question but my grammar is bad.

Comment: i can ask question  than you?

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. What do you need?

Comment: I still do not understand?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1114251/How-copy-text-with-font

Answer (score 1):

This discrepancy occurs because you're using the `RelativeLayout` quite carelessly. Relative Layout positions items relatively to one another, so it might look different across different devices.

I'd suggest that you use one vertical `LinearLayout` and to have it have 2 horizontal `LinearLayouts` as its children, as the rows in which you put these fields. I will provide some modified code of yours below, but keep in mind that this will look the same on each device, **and you need to make it look prettier**, as this is just an example. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="wawdsd"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="name"
        android:id="@+id/textView8" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="enter your name" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="copy"/>
</LinearLayout>
```